# Is spam allowed here if it looks like a real post?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, spam

I recently flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24503461/1935077) as spam and my flag was rejected with:

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

I know this looks like a real question at first, but...

- OP posted two links to clickbank.net *(e.g. `index.html` and `index.html?ep=0`)* and asks how can the server return a different page for each of them.
- According to [Clickbank's website](https://support.clickbank.com/entries/22803362-All-About-HopLinks), the poster will *earn something <sup>(1)</sup>* if someone clicks his link.
- If you click those links, you'll find out that the two pages are *almost <sup>(2)</sup>* **exactly the same**.
- OP says that those pages are ***different on lines 250 - 259***, but both files only have **235 lines**.

### The question:

Are questions like this considered spam?  I understand it's not spam when someone posts link to his website to demonstrate an issue, but in my opinion this question was posted here with purpose of getting some people who would click those links and not to learn anything <sup>(3)</sup>.

---

<sub>(1) - I din't actually read that page.</sub>
<sub>(2) - `diff "index.html" "index.html?ep=0"` will return [this](http://pastebin.com/3b3P22Pa).</sub>
<sub>(3) - Because those links are going to nowhere.</sub>

---

Here is a screenshot of the question for those who can't see deleted questions:

[image: The question I'm talking about]

Comment: Spam is treated as a very serious offence. Assume good faith whenever you can, and flag or close it with a different reason if it is not very very clear something is spam. In this case OP can legitimately wonder why that is. Edit out the links (or anonimize them with example.com) and leave a comment that a question on SO should contain code in the body itself.

Comment: If you see such things that are hard to detect as spam, it might be better to use a custom flag and explain in similar detail as in this post, rather than to flag with the spam option. Moderators have really much to do, and the more information we can give them at hand, the better they can do their decisions. They usually can't do the research you did for every flag that looks like in a greyzone.

Comment: Your link to clickbanks is not accessible to me. I get a German page (which is not so strange - websites without a Dutch version often server the German translation) saying I do not have access. (Custom 403 error page?) This may have to do with country, I am in the Netherlands.

Comment: @11684 - strange, it works for me *(I'm in Czech which is not far away)*. Can you at least access [the Google's cached version](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fsupport.clickbank.com%2Fentries%2F22803362-All-About-HopLinks&oq=cache%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fsupport.clickbank.com%2Fentries%2F22803362-All-About-HopLinks&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.1582j0j4&client=ubuntu-browser&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)?

Comment: To clarify a point:  the site does mention that a person will get *referral credit* when clicking it.  But only if a sale is successful.  If no one buys anything, then the clicking is moot.  Even so, I don't exactly see it as spam; I see it more like a poorly worded question.

Comment: @PetrR. I'm on my phone now, but I can access the cached version from it and, strange enough, even the actual link. I'll try from my desktop once more tomorrow.

Comment: `Is spam allowed here(...)` No. The rest of the question is redundant.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I rejected the flag as it appeared that the poster was just asking a very poor question.

Most of the spam we get is obviously spam - randomly generated text with links, copies of other questions/answers with a link attached - but some people have a tendency to flag *any* question with a link in it as spam regardless of what that link is.

So given that the question looks like a question (albeit a poor one) it looks like my reluctance to accept anything with a link in it as spam backfired in this case.

Don't worry about the occasional case like this. Keep flagging as you see fit and if there is a dispute bring it up here.

Answer (score 15):

> • According to Clickbank's website, the poster will earn something (1)
>   if someone clicks his link.

This is very similar to the issue with affiliation links posted on Stack Exchange Meta: [Affiliate links (Amazon and others)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2716/affiliate-links-amazon-and-others)

Jeff has answered very harshly:

```
Personally, I would flag any affiliate links as spam.

Appropriate on your blog, but not on a public forum, IMO.
```

Personally, if the question doesn't look as posted on sole purpose of attracting clicks, I'd edit out such links. If the question is useless without them, it's not a good question anyway and should be closed.

If it's an obvious spam, don't edit it, just flag.

The question you linked looks like a very poor question, but not spam (however, it could be a spam imitating a very poor question as well).