# Why was this spam flag declined?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, spam

I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28823097/why-doesnt-magento-have-any-mobile-version) as spam.  It's not an actual question, just an excuse to post two spam links to the same site.  I flagged two of this user's answers as spam (I saw them in the review queues; they also linked to that site) and both were helpful (posts deleted).

However, this question flag was declined because "flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention".

Isn't spam something moderators should be made aware of?  What (if anything) should I have done instead?

Comment: It has been flagged as a spam now.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yeah, that's spam. It seems to have been cleverly disguised as a legitimate question, only with two very obvious spam links in the last paragraph. Perhaps the moderator who declined your flags missed them somehow, or had fallen for the ruse.

For posterity, here's what the question looked like:

[image: rotten spam]

As you can see, it seems pretty innocuous at first blush, but if you look at the last paragraph, you can see two links that were very clearly shoehorned into the text. And as mentioned, they both pointed to the same unrelated website: unlike [other, real questions with just links and no code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262115/is-spam-allowed-here-if-it-looks-like-a-real-post), there was absolutely no reason for these links to exist in this question. If there was any honest question that could have been picked out from the text, these links have absolutely nothing to do with it. This is what is meant by "an *excuse* to post two spam links to the same site" (emphasis mine).

I have removed the question and destroyed the user's account now. Indeed, it was the same user who posted the two answers you had flagged earlier.

On the decline reason: you're right — spam and offensive content are among our top priorities. I normally use "no evidence to support it" to decline inappropriate spam/offensive flags for this reason.

Comment: Yeah, it took me a couple of reads to agree with this OP's assessment. Fair play to the original moderator here.

Comment: [meta-tag:status-accidentally]

Comment: Might have been a good idea to leave the question there but remove the links maybe - this post will get a lot of traffic and could have acted as a good "FYI, this is spam"

Comment: @Darren Sweeney: How about a screenshot of the deleted question instead? It's still visible to moderators and 10k users so I can grab one.

Comment: Anything really would be great - as I said, this will get traffic by it's nature and human curiosity - thanks!