# Trying to figure out why I failed this review audit

Tags: support, review-queues, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I just failed [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/7577856) and I am trying to figure out why.

At first glance, it appears to be a link only answer, but upon closer inspection I OK'd it because technically he did provide an explanation and explicitly answer the question. It may not have been a high quality answer, but [technically it was an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: BoltClock has, of course, some good specific points, but there's a general aspect you might not have considered. To quote [myself](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288506), "whenever reviewing a post, start out by taking some time to consider each of several possible flaws it might have; First Posts (FP) and Late Answers (LA), unfortunately, cover an unusually broad spectrum for review queues, so you have to keep a flexible focus and not simply hit No Action Needed just because it passes a couple of the smell tests." Just because it's *not* link-only doesn't mean it *should be kept untouched*.

Answer (score 9):

I think it has to do with the fact that the user used not one but two goo.gl URLs. Short URLs in a question or an answer are a very good sign that either the post is low quality, or if the post looks legit then the links are either non-essential to the content, or outright suspicious.

Perhaps the answer could have been saved by removing the links entirely, but in this case the post was deleted as spam and the account was removed accordingly. A quick web search reveals that the very same two goo.gl URLs are indeed spam links, completely unrelated to programming (and it looks like one unfortunate website is being hit *hard*), which confirms my statement that short URLs in posts are not to be trusted. We don't take kindly to [users who try to hide their spam links in otherwise innocuous-looking posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287259/why-was-this-spam-flag-declined/287280#287280).

I suppose, for future reference, if you encounter a post that contains short URLs, it is a good sign that the post needs improvement (even if it's simply by unwrapping the short URLs), or outright deletion (because it's spam, even if it isn't link-only). With such a generous character limit, I can't think of any good reason to use short URLs in posts, but I can think of all sorts of poor or even nefarious reasons to do so.

---

Further investigation shows that the "explanation" part of the answer is actually plagiarized from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29434657/how-to-use-sort-for-sorting-file-in-bash#comment47038569_29434657), with the "or follow this link for your problem" bit tacked on. An especially thorough reviewer will *also* note that the answer describes the `sort` command-line utility, which has absolutely nothing to do with the question at hand. Note that I don't expect reviewers to go to the extent of plagiarism-checking everything that comes up on review; I'm just demonstrating post-mortem more ways in which this post wasn't legitimate.

Comment: Those links take you to streaming video sites for Furious 7 and Frozen, so yeah, pretty clearly spam. Spammers have been copying and pasting text from other answers in their posts and then tacking on spam links at the end. Any post you see in the Low Quality Posts, First Answers, or Late Answers review queues that contains random links at the end should be examined *very* carefully.

Comment: Also, another reason why we should blacklist all common URL shorteners, in my opinion: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/257940/19679

Comment: All this just goes to show it was yet another very poor choice for use as an audit question.