# Is this spam or a legitimate edit?

Tags: discussion, edits, answers, suggested-edits, spam

I just got [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27607398/6) to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27607398/2234742) in my suggested edit review queue, and it kind of looked like spam to me (it adds a web link to a post from 2014). The page it links to has a minimal amount of content besides a code-dump.

I went with my gut feeling and clicked reject, but by the time I made my decision the system told me the edit had already been approved. What do you think? Is it spam, or is it just a legitimate edit that I am overthinking and should just leave alone?

Comment: The linked page is a blog belonging to the OP of the answer. It is also approved by the OP.

Comment: But then now does it count as "linking to own website without disclosing affiliation"?

Comment: @ace: Yeah I couldn't figure that out without clicking on too many links. This is why I open all outbound links in private browsing mode...

Comment: @ace I guess [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) would be the relevant help entry. In particular the part that says "you must disclose your affiliation in your answers."

Comment: It does certainly count as non-disclosure. The fact that he relied on someone else to add the link for him leads me to believe he's trying to hide something, but then again he clearly states in his profile that he owns the site, sooooo... I dunno. Either way the link doesn't improve upon the answer at all, and the edit summary is misleading as well to boot. I would have rejected the edit citing "editor does not know what he is doing".

Comment: @Blastfurnace: Yes. When you see spam being posted in comments don't be afraid to raise a flag on one of the *posts* the comments were left on rather than the comment itself, just to make your flag more visible. Comment spam is fiendishly difficult for us to clean up if it's bad enough.

Comment: @Blastfurnace: Oh god, there's even goo.gl links. (Somewhat relevant: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289373/trying-to-figure-out-why-i-failed-this-review-audit/289374#289374.)

Comment: @Blastfurnace: Way ahead of you ;) Thanks for your help.

Comment: @BoltClock the original edit mentioned in the question has not been rolled-back yet. Looking at the edit history, Martijn removed the same link back in July, so it magically reappearing in an edit (along with links in comments) certainly seems deliberate.

Comment: Possibly multiple accounts?

Comment: @Qix I don't think multiple accounts is against the ToS, but using them as "sock puppet accounts" to manipulate votes, traffic, etc is. Can 10k+ rep members view the IP address from which posts/changes were made? Most puppet masters don't both using alt. proxies.